Please help understanding Marinov's generator
I've been working through an interesting puzzle in classical electromagnetism with a fellow researcher, and we've hit a wall. We're hoping the physics community might be able to shed some light on where our reasoning is going wrong. The setup is as follows:
Consider two infinitely long solenoids, S1 and S2, with their axes parallel to the z-axis. Solenoid S1 crosses the xy-plane at (0,b) and S2 crosses at (0,-b). Each solenoid carries a current in opposite directions.
We now introduce a conductive ring that is centered on the z-axis and lies in the xy-plane. Two electric brushes are placed at diametrically opposite positions on the ring.

Outside the solenoids, the magnetic field B = 0, but the magnetic vector potential A ≠ 0 and varies with position according to:
$$
A_r(\phi)=\frac{B_0 R^2b\left(r^2+b^2 \right)cos\phi}{\left(r^2+b^2 \right)^2-4b^2r^2sin^2\phi}
$$
$$
A_\phi(\phi)=\frac{B_0 R^2b\left(r^2-b^2 \right)sin\phi}{\left(r^2+b^2 \right)^2-4b^2r^2sin^2\phi}
$$
Where $B_0$ is the magnetic flux density inside the solenoids.
We then consider two cases:
Case 1: The solenoids rotate around the z-axis, while the conductive ring is fixed.
Case 2: The solenoids are fixed, while the conductive ring rotates around the z-axis.
Our analysis, done for both cases from the lab fixed coordinate system, led us to the following conclusions:
In case 1 (rotating solenoids), there should be a time-varying A field at any fixed point on the ring, which would induce an EMF between the two brushes on the ring through the line integral of $\partial \vec{A}/\partial t$.
In case 2 (rotating ring), we initially thought there would be no EMF between the brushes, since B = 0 outside the solenoids. However, this led to a paradox - the two cases should be equivalent from a relativity standpoint, but we were getting different predictions for the EMF.
I expected the EMF to depend only on the relative motion between the conductive ring and the solenoids, and not on the relative motion of each element with respect to the fixed lab frame.
After much discussion, we realized that the partial time derivative ∂A/∂t may not be the correct way to formulate the problem, and that the total derivative dA/dt should be used instead. This seemed to resolve the paradox, by adding extra induction terms through the convective derivative, but then we ran into issues reconciling this with the standard form of Maxwell's equations.
We've consulted several advanced electromagnetism texts, but haven't found a satisfactory resolution to this puzzle. It seems to touch on deeper questions about the role of vector potentials, gauge invariance, and the proper formulation of electromagnetic theory in moving frames.
Have any of you encountered a similar paradox before? Can you suggest how we might properly analyze this scenario to obtain consistent, physically meaningful results?
Thank you very much in advance for your replies.
